# ProFTPd won't start - proftpd.serviceJob for proftpd.service failed

Tags: ftp, proftpd

I'm done - I don't get ProFTPd to start... I tried everything. If I start proftpd with

> /etc/init.d/proftpd start

I get the following:

> [....] Starting proftpd (via systemctl): proftpd.serviceJob for
>   proftpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status proftpd.service' and
>   'journalctl -xn' for details.  failed!

Output of "systemctl status proftpd.service":

> ● proftpd.service - LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon    Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/init.d/proftpd)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri
>   2016-09-09 17:54:42 CEST; 18s ago   Process: 2781
>   ExecStart=/etc/init.d/proftpd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Sep 09 17:54:42 root.MYDOMAIN.de proftpd[2781]: Starting ftp server:
>   proftpd2016-09-09 17:54:42,110 root.MYDOMAIN.de proftpd[2787]:
>   warning: handling possibly truncated confi...roftpd.conf' Sep 09
>   17:54:42 root.MYDOMAIN.de proftpd[2781]: 2016-09-09 17:54:42,113
>   root.MYDOMAIN.de proftpd[2787]: warning: unable to determine IP
>   address of 'root.MYDOMAIN.de' Sep 09 17:54:42 root.MYDOMAIN.de
>   proftpd[2781]: 2016-09-09 17:54:42,114 root.MYDOMAIN.de proftpd[2787]:
>   error: no valid servers configured Sep 09 17:54:42 root.MYDOMAIN.de
>   proftpd[2781]: 2016-09-09 17:54:42,114 root.MYDOMAIN.de proftpd[2787]:
>   fatal: error processing configuration file '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'
>   Sep 09 17:54:42 root.MYDOMAIN.de proftpd[2781]: failed! Sep 09
>   17:54:42 root.MYDOMAIN.de systemd[1]: proftpd.service: control process
>   exited, code=exited status=1 Sep 09 17:54:42 root.MYDOMAIN.de
>   systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon. Sep 09
>   17:54:42 root.MYDOMAIN.de systemd[1]: Unit proftpd.service entered
>   failed state. Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in
>   full.

journal output:

> -- Logs begin at Thu 2016-09-08 14:58:07 CEST, end at Fri 2016-09-09 17:58:10 CEST. -- Sep 09 17:58:01 root.MYDMOMAIN.de CRON[2892]: (root)
>   CMD (/home/ts/statuscheck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1) Sep 09 17:58:01
>   root.MYDMOMAIN.de CRON[2891]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed
>   for user root Sep 09 17:58:10 root.MYDMOMAIN.de proftpd[2912]: Starting
>   ftp server: proftpd2016-09-09 17:58:10,195 root.MYDMOMAIN.de
>   proftpd[2918]: warning: handling possibly truncated configuration data
>   a t line 188 of '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf' Sep 09 17:58:10
>   root.MYDMOMAIN.de proftpd[2912]: 2016-09-09 17:58:10,201
>   root.MYDMOMAIN.de proftpd[2918]: warning: unable to determine IP
>   address of 'root.MYDMOMAIN.de' Sep 09 17:58:10 root.MYDMOMAIN.de
>   proftpd[2912]: 2016-09-09 17:58:10,202 root.MYDMOMAIN.de proftpd[2918]:
>   error: no valid servers configured Sep 09 17:58:10 root.MYDMOMAIN.de
>   proftpd[2912]: 2016-09-09 17:58:10,202 root.MYDMOMAIN.de proftpd[2918]:
>   fatal: error processing configuration file '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'
>   Sep 09 17:58:10 root.MYDMOMAIN.de proftpd[2912]: failed! Sep 09
>   17:58:10 root.MYDMOMAIN.de systemd[1]: proftpd.service: control process
>   exited, code=exited status=1 Sep 09 17:58:10 root.MYDMOMAIN.de
>   systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon.
>   -- Subject: Unit proftpd.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> ### -- Unit proftpd.service has failed.
>
> -- The result is failed. Sep 09 17:58:10 root.MYDMOMAIN.de systemd[1]: Unit proftpd.service entered failed state.

Two thing I don't understand:

1. "unable to determine IP address of 'root.MYDMOMAIN.de'" what does this mean? Have I to set a subdomain with "root"?
2. "error processing configuration file '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'" config broken? I checked my config with another config from another server - it's the same...

If you need the proftpd.conf tell me - post would be to long for that.

Pls help me :( thanks.

Comment: The root cause is `unable to determine IP address of 'root.MYDOMAIN.de`; this indicates that ProFTPD cannot resolve that DNS hostname to an IP address via the nameservers configured in `/etc/resolv.conf` (or via the static map in `/etc/hosts`).  FTP requires IP addresses, so ProFTPD ensures, on startup, that the server is reachable via a resolvable IP address.

Answer (score 0):

is this an real domain or an fqdn? When its an real domain try this:

Go to your Provider, where you hosted the Domain and do an a record on root.yourdomain.com to your server.

Example:

root.yourdomain.com A YourIP

When this is not working try this:

root.yourdomain.com A YourIP:21

Answer (score 0):

Need config files to be sure, but there seem to be at least two possibilities. Either a malformed config file or an invalid hostname. Use the command

```
hostname --fqdn
```

to get the fully qualified dns hostname. Put that hostname in your  tag like so

```
<VirtualHost myhost.internal.xyz.cloudsrvc.net>
  # Put vhost config here
</VirtualHost>
```

(assuming hostname --fqdn returned myhost.internal.xyz.cloudsrvc.net) and restart the service.

It's also possible your host is not mapped by DNS, in which case you may need to use the IP address instead. If you again get the same error, try using the IPv4 address in the  tag like so

```
<VirtualHost 138.199.111.14>
  # Put vhost config here
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart the service again. If that works but the hostname did not, check your DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Dec 31 13:38:39 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: proftpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 31 13:38:39 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: ProFTPD FTP server.

whats wrong

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/538851)